# Pontryagin square: lifting to an integral cocycle, and an element $H^4 (B^2 \mathbb{Z}_r, \mathbb{Z}_{2r})=$Hom$(\mathbb{Z}_{2r},\mathbb{Z}_{2r})$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Let $M$ be a simplicial complex and $Π$ be a finite abelian group. In
the simplest case $Π = \mathbb{Z}_r$ finite group with $r$ even, the Pontryagin square is a cohomological operation which maps an element 
$f ∈ H^p(M,\mathbb Z_r)$, $p$ even, to an element $\in H^{2p}(M,\mathbb Z_{2r})$.

> Questions:

- If the homology group $H_{p−1}(M,\mathbb Z)$ is torsion-free. Then how can we show that every $p$-cocycle modulo $r$ can be lifted to an integral $p$-cocycle. If $\tilde f$ is a lift of $f$, we define
  $Pf = \tilde f ∪ \tilde f \mod 2r$.
  How do we prove that this is well-defined (i.e. independent of the choice
  of the lift)?
- If the homology group $H_{p−1}(M,\mathbb Z)$ is NOT torsion-free. Can we still define the
  $$
  f ∈ H^p(M,\mathbb Z_r)?$$
  And its lifting to an integral $p$-cocycle?
- Say $p=2$, then how to show that the Pontryagin square can be thought of as a distinguished element in $$H^4 (B^2 \mathbb  Z_r, \mathbb  Z_{2r}) \simeq
  \text{Hom}(\mathbb  Z_{2r},\mathbb  Z_{2r}),$$ is this true? In fact, does it corresponds to the **identity element in Hom$(\mathbb  Z_{2r},\mathbb  Z_{2r})$?** Does the latter also provide a quadratic refinement of twice the cup product?